# python, create a series of lists from two other lists with index

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, nested-for-loop

HELLO thank you in advance for your help, I've been trying to learn python on my own over the last few months!

I have two list of lists :

```
countries_list =  [['Canada'], ['China'], ['Finland'], ...]
ratios = [[10.2, 10.3, 11.4,  12.0], [8.2, 8.1, 9.0, 9.1], [15.4, 15.5, 15.8, 16.0], ...]
```

I want to merge the lists together according to the indices.  For example, `countries[0] = ['Canada']` and `ratios[0] = [10.2, 10.3, 11.4,  12.0]`. I want to use the indices to create this final list:

```
final_list = [[10.2, 10.3, 11.4,  12.0, 'Canada'], [8.2, 8.1, 9.0, 9.1,'China'], [15.4, 15.5, 15.8, 16.0, 'Finland']...]
```

this is the code I've come up with for now:

```
final_list = []
for countries in countries_list:
    for ratio_list in ratios:
        current_ratios = []
        for r in ratio_list:
            current_ratios.append(r)
        current_ratios.append(countries)
    rows_list.append(current_ratios)
print(rows_list)
```

this is the output:

```
[[9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Eswatini'], [9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Bahamas'], [9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Jamaica'], [9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Chad'], [9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Kenya'], [9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Mali'], [9.8, 10.3, 10.9, 11.4, 12.0, 12.6, 14.8, 19.2, 25.2, 'Guyana'] ...]
```

As you can see, it is kinda close to the desired outcome, but the ratios are always the same. The nested loops are very confusing to me and I find myself wondering what the ordering is and just what's happening here in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` + list-comprehension:

```py
countries_list = [["Canada"], ["China"], ["Finland"]]
ratios = [
    [10.2, 10.3, 11.4, 12.0],
    [8.2, 8.1, 9.0, 9.1],
    [15.4, 15.5, 15.8, 16.0],
]

out = [[*r, *c] for c, r in zip(countries_list, ratios)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [10.2, 10.3, 11.4, 12.0, "Canada"],
    [8.2, 8.1, 9.0, 9.1, "China"],
    [15.4, 15.5, 15.8, 16.0, "Finland"],
]
```

Comment: There's also an option with [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and [`concat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.concat): `list(starmap(concat, zip(ratios, countries_list)))`. It should be slightly faster.

Comment: Hey! Could you take a moment to explain what the * symbol means? or could you point to some documentation? thanks a lot!

Comment: @shapeless_maxi, it's [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). `[*r, *c]` equal to `r + c` which is lists concatenation.

Comment: @OlvinRoght sick ill take a look into that a bit more